# calculate sum of rows in pandas dataframe grouped by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv that I loaded into a Pandas Dataframe.

I then select only the rows with duplicate dates in the DF:

```
df_dups = df[df.duplicated(['Date'])].copy()
```

I'm trying to get the sum of all the rows with the exact same date for 4 columns (all float values), like this:

```
df_sum = df_dups.groupby('Date')["Received Quantity","Sent Quantity","Fee Amount","Market Value"].sum()
```

However, this does not give the desired result. When I examine df_sum.groups, I've noticed that it did not include the first date in the indices. So for two items with the same date, there would only be one index in the groups object.

```
pprint(df_dups.groupby('Date')["Received Quantity","Sent Quantity","Fee Amount","Market Value"].groups)
```

I have no idea how to get the sum of all duplicates.

I've also tried:

```
df_sum = df_dups.groupby('Date')["Received Quantity","Sent Quantity","Fee Amount","Market Value"].apply(lambda x : x.sum())
```

This gives the same result, which makes sense I guess, as the indices in the groupby object are not complete. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please update your post to include a sample of your DataFrame using `df.head(10).to_dict()` and your expected output.

Comment: the group by sum looks correct.  why do you think it is producing wrong results?  have you forward filled nans

Comment: `df[df.duplicated(['Date'])]` by default excludes the first rows for each date. You want `df[df.duplicated('Date', keep=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for the method `duplicated`. By default duplicates are marked with `True` except for the first occurence, which is why the first date is not included in your sums.

You only need to pass in `keep=False` in `duplicated` for your desired behaviour.

```
df_dups = df[df.duplicated(['Date'], keep=False)].copy()
```

After that the sum can be calculated properly with the expression you wrote

```
df_sum = df_dups.groupby('Date')["Received Quantity","Sent Quantity","Fee Amount","Market Value"].apply(lambda x : x.sum())
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem. Thx!